# Datamapper with existing database- tables with primary key column name other than id

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I am running a application using codeigniter framework. I have a database. I want to implement datamapper ORM. Since for datamapper- "Every table must have a primary key named id".

I have an auto increment integer field in all tables. But the column name is not "id" in all cases. In my `user` table, the auto-increment integer column name is `user_id` instead of `id`. What changes do i need to make to work with Datamapper ?

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

SELECT *
FROM (`user`)
WHERE `id` =  200

Filename: D:\Projects\DealVector\dealvector\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution apart from editing the native datamapper library. I modified the function _get_by() in datamapper class in /application/libraries/datamapper.php as below. i added `var $table = 'user';
    var $id = 'user_id';` in my model and added `if($field=='id'){
            $field = $this->id;
        }` in datamappper library.

```
/**
 * Get By
 *
 * Gets objects by specified field name and value.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @param   string $field Field to look at.
 * @param   array $value Arguments to this method.
 * @return  DataMapper Returns self for method chaining.
 */
private function _get_by($field, $value = array())
{
    //Custom Change
    if($field=='id'){
        $field = $this->id;
    }

    if (isset($value[0]))
    {
        $this->where($field, $value[0]);
    }

    return $this->get();
}
```